# What Dua can I make to ask Allah to ease the difficulties of another person?

Tags: dua

I found this Dua: https://hamariweb.com/islam/musibat_zada_ko_dekhte_waqt_ki_dua_md48.aspx

الحَمْدُ للهِ الَّذِي عَافَانِي مِمَّا ابْتَلاكَ بِهِ، وَفَضَّلَنِي عَلَى كَثيْر ٍ مِمَّنْ خَلَقَ تَفْضِيْلا.ً

This supplication is to be said to one’s self, not directly to the one in trial or tribulation.
‘All praise is for Allah Who saved me from that which He tested you with and Who most certainly favoured me over much of His creation.’

**My interpretation** of this Dua is that it is said when seeing someone else in trouble and giving thanks to Allah that I myself did not suffer this trouble.

Well, what about a Dua to ask Allah to seek refuge for the person I see in trouble? Could I change the wording of the following to make everything from first person tense to third person tense?
اللَّهُمَّ إنِّي أَسألُكَ فِعْلَ الْخَيْرَاتِ، وَتَرْكَ الْمُنْكَرَاتِ، وَحُبَّ الْمَسَاكِينِ، وَأَنْ تَغْفِرَ لِي، وَتَرْحَمَنِي، وَإِذَا أَرَدْتَ فِتْنَةَ قَوْمٍ فَتَوَفَّنِي غَيْرَ مَفْتُونٍ، وَأَسْأَلُكَ حُبَّكَ، وَحُبَّ مَنْ يُحِبُّكَ، وَحُبَّ عَمَلٍ يُقَرِّبُنِي إِلَى حُبِّكَ

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 0):

```
                 حَسْبُنَا اللَّهُ وَنِعْمَ الْوَكِيلُ
```

Allah (Alone) is Sufficient for us, and He is the Best Disposer of affairs (for us).

This a very powerful small ayah. My personally experienced dua whenever I was in any difficulty I start reciting this words, everything become simple for me automatically. When you feel any fear and anxiety only start reciting this powerful ayah...Allah will help you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be a specific dua. A Muslim can additionally make up their own supplications, so long as nothing haraam is being asked for in the supplication. So you could in reality say your own supplication for a person with difficulties; for their difficulties to be eased. There are certain times when Allah has promised if we call upon Him at that time then He will answer our supplication (ie when it's raining, the last 3rd of the night following tahajjud, if an oppressed one calls upon Allah)

In The Qu'ran. Allah says: When My servants ask about Me, I am indeed close to them. I listen to the prayer of every supplicant, when he calls on Me. Let them also, with a will, listen to My call, and believe in Me, so that they may walk in the right way (Surah Al Baqarah 2 ayah 186)

Talking of Tahajjud:
Worship Him in a portion of the night and glorify Him through the night (Qu'ran 76:26)

The Prophet (S.a.W) highly recommends Tahajjud prayer and said "Make a habit of observing Tahajud prayer. It was the custom of the pious before you. It draws you close to you Lord, and keeps you away from sins" (Al- Tirmidhi)

Talking of the rain:
When rain falls, as it is said in the hadith of Sahl ibn Sa'd that is attributed to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): "There are two which will not be rejected: du'aa' at the time of the call (to prayer) and when it is raining." (Abu Dawood)

Travelling for a good purpose:
"Three supplications will not be rejected (by Allah (SWT)), the supplication of the parent for his child, the supplication of the one who is fasting, and the supplication of the traveler" (Al-Tirmidhi)

Asking for that which is haraam, referring to the situation of Abu Salamah when he had just passed away and had closed his eyes, he (s.a.w) said:
Do not ask for yourselves anything but good, for the angels will say 'Ameen' to all that you ask for. O Allah, forgive Abu Salamah, and raise his ranks among those who are guided.' (Muslim, Abu Dawud)

Drinking zamzam water with the intention of it curing some kind of illness or bringing some kind of benefit:
"Jaber narrated that Allah's Messenger (s.a.w) said: 'Zam Zam water is for what it is drunk for" (Ahmad).

Fasting:
The dua of a fasting person is accepted in shaa Allah. The Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said; three supplications will not be rejected (by Allah (SWT)), the supplication of the parent for his child, the supplication of the one who is fasting, and the supplication of the traveler. (Al- Tirmidhi)

and the dua of the one fasting at the time of breaking fast:
The Prophet (s.a.w) declared, 'Three men whose dua is never rejected (by Allah) are: when a fasting person breaks fast (in another narration, the fasting person until he breaks his fast), the just ruler and the one who is oppressed.' (Al- Tirmidhi)

This link may also provide some insightful information.
https://aboutislam.net/spirituality/4-ways-to-feed-the-soul-this-ramadan/

And Allah knows best